Lepton 3.5 thermal camera is too bright and impossible to recognize object
i'm trying to display Lepton 3.5 thermal camera which is uvc on Raspberry pi 5.
It can be displayed well using opencv but i need the maximum temperature of frame so this code is what i'm using.

The above image is the result of running the code on my pc and it displays well but on pi 5 the frame is too bright as below image.

The code is identical but the result is not. Also the library(libuvc) version is identical.
The below output is the result of v4l2-ctl --info on both host.
# PC
$ v4l2-ctl --info --device=/dev/video0
Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Card type        : PureThermal (fw:v1.3.0): PureTh
        Bus info         : usb-0000:02:00.0-2.4
        Driver version   : 6.7.6
        Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
                Video Capture
                Metadata Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Model            : PureThermal (fw:v1.3.0): PureTh
        Serial           : 001a0012-5119-3038-3532-373600000000
        Bus info         : usb-0000:02:00.0-2.4
        Media version    : 6.7.6
        Hardware revision: 0x00000200 (512)
        Driver version   : 6.7.6
Interface Info:
        ID               : 0x03000002
        Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
        ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
        Name             : PureThermal (fw:v1.3.0): PureTh
        Function         : V4L2 I/O
        Flags            : default
        Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
          Link 0x02000022: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 3' (Video Pixel Formatter): Data, Enabled, Immutable

# PI
$ v4l2-ctl --info --device=/dev/video0
Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Card type        : PureThermal (fw:v1.3.0): PureTh
        Bus info         : usb-xhci-hcd.1-1.4
        Driver version   : 6.6.20
        Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
                Video Capture
                Metadata Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Model            : PureThermal (fw:v1.3.0): PureTh
        Serial           : 001a0012-5119-3038-3532-373600000000
        Bus info         : usb-xhci-hcd.1-1.4
        Media version    : 6.6.20
        Hardware revision: 0x00000200 (512)
        Driver version   : 6.6.20
Interface Info:
        ID               : 0x03000002
        Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
        ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
        Name             : PureThermal (fw:v1.3.0): PureTh
        Function         : V4L2 I/O
        Flags            : default
        Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
          Link 0x02000022: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 3' (Video Pixel Formatter): Data, Enabled, Immutable

My question is

Why the frame is too bright on pi?
How to fix this bug?

If anyone knows how to fix this issue please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If anyone knows how to fix this issue please let me know ... this site is not for chatting ... all you have to do, is to post a clear question and someone will try to answer it
